# Does Facebook use WordPress to fully develop some of its websites

Tags: wordpress

I want to know if Facebook uses WordPress to fully create any of its web pages because I use a plugin in my browser that is able to detect sites developed with WordPress. So I opened one of Facebook's sub domains and the plugin says it uses WordPress. I was a bit surprised because I thought a huge company with lots of engineers would prefer developing a site from scratch to better suit its needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Here is one of their subdomains, built fully with WordPress:

http://newsroom.fb.com/